# Wordpress category name for the first loop cycle is null

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, shortcode

I'm creating a shortcode that displays a slider. Each slide should display the **Project Name**, **Project Category**,and **Fetaured Image**. I've managed to display all these content however, on the first item loop the Project Category is not displaying and when I check using '**var_dump()**' function it says '**NULL**'.

Frontend output screenshot: https://prnt.sc/12tyznt

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6xd1.png)

Here's my shortcode below:

```
function create_cptslider_shortcode() {
    $output = '<div class="cpt-slider">';
        $output .= '<div class="owl-carousel">';

            $args_query = array(
                'post_type' => 'project',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby' => 'date',
                'order' => 'DESC'
            ); $query = new WP_Query( $args_query );
        
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    
                    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'category' );
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $pCat = $term->name;
                    }
                    
                    $query->the_post(); 
                        $output .= '
                        <div class="cpt-slide-bg" style="background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'medium')[0].');">
                            <div class="cpt-slide-cat">'.$pCat.'</div>
                            <div class="cpt-slide">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                            <div class="bg-color"></div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
            } else {
                $output .= 'No Posts';
            } 
        wp_reset_query();
        $output .= '</div>';    
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'cpt_slider', 'create_cptslider_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_the_ID()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_id/) instead of `$post->ID`

```
function create_cptslider_shortcode() {
    $output = '<div class="cpt-slider">';
        $output .= '<div class="owl-carousel">';

            $args_query = array(
                'post_type'      => 'project',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                'order'          => 'DESC'
            ); 

            $query = new WP_Query( $args_query );
        
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    
                    $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID() , 'category' );
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                        $pCat = $term->name;
                    }
                    
                    $query->the_post(); 
                        $output .= '
                        <div class="cpt-slide-bg" style="background-image: url('.wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'medium')[0].');">
                            <div class="cpt-slide-cat">'.$pCat.'</div>
                            <div class="cpt-slide">'.get_the_title().'</div>
                            <div class="bg-color"></div>
                        </div>
                    ';
                }
            } else {
                $output .= 'No Posts';
            } 
            wp_reset_query();
        $output .= '</div>';    
    $output .= '</div>';

    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'cpt_slider', 'create_cptslider_shortcode' );
```

Comment: @Kryslerr Lisondra Does my answer help?